# Do all dynamic languages support duck typing?

Tags: php, types, duck-typing

Do all dynamic languages support [duck typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing)?

I would think that PHP supports duck typing. Is that the case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Any dynamically-typed oop language** supports duck-typing, including php.

It's not a feature, it's rather programming style.

Comment: Duck Typing is most definitely a language feature, not a programming style. A dynamically typed language *could* declare and enforce types for method calls, and if it did, then it would not support duck typing.

Answer (score 4):

Static typing means that once you have defined a variable, it stays the same type for its lifetime. Static languages usually require that you declare the type, but some have type inference--they will infer the type from the definition. In scala, for example, you can write `i = 1` and the compiler will infer the type of `i` to be `int`, but you can't then declare `i = "1"`, that will throw an error.

Dynamic typing means that you don't have to declare the type of a variable and you can change the type of a variable. In ruby, you can follow `i = 1` with `i = "1"` and there is no problem at all.

Duck typing is a different concept that applies almost exclusively to object oriented languages. In a language with Duck typing, arguments to a method are not checked for type, so any type that you pass into the method is acceptable as long as it responds to any calls it receives.

So, for example:

```
class Duck
  def quacks
    puts "Quack"
  end
end

class FauxDuck
  def quacks
    puts "FauxQuack"
  end
end

def quacker duck
  duck.quacks
end
```

The method quacker will take either a Duck or a FauxDuck, because either will respond to `.quacks`

While most object-oriented dynamically typed languages are also duck typed, it isn't a requirement. You could have a language that declared types to method calls and enforced them, but was still dynamically typed--remember, dynamic typing just means that you can change the type of an object after you've defined it.

In hypothetical non-duck typed ruby

```
class Duck
  def quacks
    puts "Quack"
  end
end

class FauxDuck
  def quacks
    puts "FauxQuack"
  end
end

def quacker Duck duck
  duck.quacks
end

duck = Duck.new
quacker.duck ## no error
duck = FauxDuck.new ##redefining the type of the variable
quacker.duck ## throws an error at runtime
```

Why you would want to do this, I don't know, but it's a choice available to language designers.

Comment: Is Duck Typing used in Strategy Pattern?

Answer (score -3):

Yes, PHP is a duck-typed language.

```
$x = 1;
$x = 'string';
$x = new Person;
$x = 1 / 2;
```

Comment: What about the first question?

Comment: this is not about duck-typing, `$duck->quack()` is (not caring about actual class of $duck just about it can quack)